# Looking for potential leak

Tags: memory-leaks

**Code in C#**

```
string GetValue() 
{  
   //m_IFC is RCW of a native COM object returns Variant marshalled as managed object    
   object value1 = m_IFC.GetValue();   
   string valueStr = (string) value1;    
   return valueStr;  
}
```

The assembly having above code is hosted in COM out-of-proc server which returns the received string from the API to all clients.
Are there any any potential memory leaks here?

Answer (score 0):

From the code you show there is no potential memory leak if `m_IFC` is indeed a standard runtime callable wrapper. From the [MSDN documetation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8bwh56xe(v=vs.110).aspx):

> The standard wrapper enforces built-in marshaling rules. For example, when a .NET client passes a String type as part of an argument to an unmanaged object, the wrapper converts the string to a BSTR type. Should the COM object return a BSTR to its managed caller, the caller receives a String. Both the client and the server send and receive data that is familiar to them.

All objects shown in your code are managed types and will be garbage collected when all references to it go out of scope. Any unmanaged memory is already handled by the wrapper.